# how to get ptree visualize tool?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I saw a tutorial which use "ptree" tool to draw the tree graph (shown below)

[image]

but when I use the same tool, the result is not the same as above

[image]

my OS is ubuntu 11.10, does any one know about it??

google the keyword "ptree" does not return useful information

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `ptree` on your second machine is a completely different tool which has (by coincidence) the same name as your `ptree` on the first machine.

On the first machine you are using a tool which parses an ascii representation of a tree and prints it in a graphical fashion.

On the second machine you are using a tool from the package `adacontrol` which is about the language *Ada* and can print the logical nestings of ASIS statements.

I guess these two tools are not the same.

Maybe you can find out where the tool on the first computer came from?

Comment: got it and thank you, I think the "ptree" tool in first machine maybe the close source tool, that's why no useful google result for me!